# Does verbal communication negate invisibility's advantage? If not, does it give enemies more of a chance at hitting the invisible character?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, invisibility

Let's say you have an invisible character who shouts a warning to one of their teammates to alert him/ her that they're in danger. Does that automatically pinpoint the invisible character? If not an automatic thing, should enemies near the invisible character be given a free chance at detecting where the invisible character is at? Even if the invisible character is able to stealthily move away after their warning, do enemies have an increased chance at hitting him/ her because the enemies know that there's an invisible character in the vicinity?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does that automatically pinpoint the invisible character? **NO**

If not an automatic thing, should enemies near the invisible character be given a free chance at detecting where the invisible character is at? **YES**

Even if the invisible character is able to stealthily move away after their warning, do enemies have an increased chance at hitting him/ her because the enemies know that there's an invisible character in the vicinity? **NO**

> A character can use Listen to notice the presence of an invisible creature (generally opposed by a Move Silently check). If the character beats the DC by 20 or more, he or she can pinpoint the location of the invisible creature, though it still maintains total concealment from the character (50% miss chance).

[From SRD](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Listen_Skill)

Since detecting a person speaking is DC 0, you almost automatically notice the presence of the invisible character, but you need to beat DC 20 to know the exact location.

You don't get any bonuses for hitting the invisible target, because invisibility has nothing to do with sound. It grants you total concealment and that's it. And the quote reads explicitly that total concealment is maintained. So the opponents still have 50% miss chance against the invisible character.

> A successful attack into a square occupied by an enemy with total concealment has a 50% miss chance

[From SRD](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Concealment)

That is any character who knows exact square where the invisible creature is can attack into this square with 50% miss chance. It doesn't matter how does he know that. He may even attack a random square and if he accidentally attacks the right one he gets the same 50% miss chance. So if any one of the group discerns the location of the invisible opponent, he can inform everybody else to let them attack proper location with the same efficiency.

**To sum up**. The enemies can pinpoint the exact location of the invisible character if he speaks, but they get no other benefits.

NOTE. In Pathfinder there is no Listen skill. You will need to use Perception instead.

Comment: (related, but *slightly* different) can knowledge of about where an invisible creature is help others pinpoint it more accurately? For instance "I heard him over here when he spoke" (and point in the appropriate direction) provided there's nowhere for the invisible creature to flee?

Comment: >A successful attack into a square occupied by an enemy with total concealment has a 50% miss chance. That is any carracter can point at a square where the invisible character is and then other characters can attack into this square and hit with 50% chance.

Comment: Note that enemies DO have an increased chance of hitting an invisible shouting character, since before they wouldn't have even thought to attack squares they couldn't see anyone in. Now they will. Also, for Pathfinder you would use the Stealth and Perception skills.

Comment: Thank you both. With the extra information, that fully answers the question(s) I had regarding the rules.

Comment: To add to @GreySage's comment: the increased chance here is not reflected via any game mechanic (so no numerical advantage), but purely in terms of the ability to make more informed decisions.